# Update rows based on a recursive CTE query result

Tags: mysql, cte, recursive

This query shows all lines recursively based on a uuid / parentUUID relationship:

```
WITH RECURSIVE files_paths (id, parent) AS
(
  SELECT uuid, parentuuid
    FROM core_data
    WHERE uuid = '2c828bbb-71c4-4a00-8d54-d1a4575ec3ef'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.uuid, e.parentuuid
    FROM files_paths AS ep JOIN core_data AS e
      ON ep.id = e.parentuuid
)
SELECT id FROM files_paths
```

However if I need to update lines with provided id (as follows) the query fails:

```
UPDATE `core_data` SET `attrib` = 'test' WHERE `uuid` IN (SELECT id FROM files_paths)
```

(Error is "You have an error near...")

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually using MariaDB? It only supports SELECT after a CTE, not UPDATE.

Answer (score 2):

You must declare your CTE inside the update statement. Here is a trivial [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9ca42b365cfb1e4af653e3694e6a358):

```
create table cd 
( id int not null primary key
, parent_id int references cd (id)
, visited int default 0 not null
);

insert into cd (id, parent_id) values (1,null),(2,1),(3,1),(4,2);

-- no nodes visited
select * from cd;

id  parent_id   visited
1       0
2   1   0
3   1   0
4   2   0

with recursive cte (i,p) as ( 
    select id, parent_id from cd where id = 2 
    union all 
    select id, parent_id 
    from cte join cd on cd.parent_id = cte.i
)
update cd set visited = 1 where id in (select i from cte);

select * from cd;

id  parent_id   visited
1       0
2   1   1
3   1   0
4   2   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've found and that works both in MariaDB and MySQL:

```
UPDATE `core_data` SET `attrib` = 'test' WHERE `uuid` IN (
  WITH RECURSIVE files_paths (id, parent) AS
  (
    SELECT uuid, parentuuid
      FROM core_data
      WHERE uuid = '2c828bbb-71c4-4a00-8d54-d1a4575ec3ef'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.uuid, e.parentuuid
      FROM files_paths AS ep JOIN core_data AS e
        ON ep.id = e.parentuuid
  )
  SELECT id FROM files_paths
)
```